# Add new configurable field of datetime type via system.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I have a module and system.xml file inside my etc folder. I have added text fields and select box type configurable fields through this xml file.

Now I need to add a new field which should show a date time picker and receive date time values in it.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

etc/system.xml:

```
<date translate="label">
    <label>Date</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>your_module/date</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>    
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</date>
```

Block/Date.php

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Block_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;
        $format = 'MM/d/y';

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );

        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat($format);
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

If in doubt see as used in my module

[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-store-maintenance.html](http://bit.ly/dexxtz-store-maintenance)